# need help solving weird build failure using a Ubuntu machine

Tags: 22.04, nodejs, javascript

My best guess is that something is corrupted on the machine, but I have yet to figure out what. The machine is running Ubuntu 22.04. The issue is trivial to reproduce:

```
yarn create vite my-vue-app --template vue
cd my-vue-app
yarn add cesium vite-plugin-cesium vite -D
```

Updating `vite.config.js` to:

```
// vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import cesium from 'vite-plugin-cesium'
import path from 'path'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue(), cesium()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src')
    }
  }
})
```

In HelloWorld.vue, import cesium with `import * as Cesium from 'cesium'`

Then, running `yarn dev`, the following error is generated:

```
✘ [ERROR] Failed to resolve entry for package "https". The package may have incorrect main/module/exports specified in its package.json. [plugin vite:dep-pre-bundle]

    node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1373:21:
      1373 │         let result = await callback({
           ╵                      ^

    at packageEntryFailure (file:///home/me/projects/test/my-vue-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:28725:11)
    at resolvePackageEntry (file:///home/me/projects/test/my-vue-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:28722:5)
    at tryNodeResolve (file:///home/me/projects/test/my-vue-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:28453:20)
    at Context.resolveId (file:///home/me/projects/test/my-vue-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:28212:28)
    at Object.resolveId (file:///home/me/projects/test/my-vue-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:44276:64)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async file:///home/me/projects/test/my-vue-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:65922:21
    at async file:///home/me/projects/test/my-vue-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:39976:34
    at async requestCallbacks.on-resolve (/home/me/projects/test/my-vue-app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1373:22)
    at async handleRequest (/home/me/projects/test/my-vue-app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:729:13)


  This error came from the "onResolve" callback registered here:

    node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1292:20:
      1292 │       let promise = setup({
           ╵                     ^

    at setup (file:///home/me/projects/test/my-vue-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:39956:19)
    at handlePlugins (/home/me/projects/test/my-vue-app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1292:21)
    at buildOrContextImpl (/home/me/projects/test/my-vue-app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:978:5)
    at Object.buildOrContext (/home/me/projects/test/my-vue-app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:786:5)
    at /home/me/projects/test/my-vue-app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:2186:68
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.context (/home/me/projects/test/my-vue-app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:2186:27)
    at Object.context (/home/me/projects/test/my-vue-app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:2026:58)
    at prepareEsbuildOptimizerRun (file:///home/me/projects/test/my-vue-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:46041:35)

  The plugin "vite:dep-pre-bundle" was triggered by this import

    node_modules/@cesium/engine/Source/Core/Resource.js:2076:48:
      2076 │       return URL.protocol === "https:" ? import("https") : import("http");
           ╵                                                 ~~~~~~~
```

What makes this strange is that I can setup up a fresh Ubuntu install in a VM with VirtualBox and everything will work as expected.

Additionally, trying this on MacOS works as well.

I need this simple, sample project to build and run on my machine. It won't. It will if I setup a fresh Ubuntu install inside of a VM, for example. I do not know what the difference is between the VM and my machine. They are configured the same

If anyone has any thoughts on what could be going wrong, things to check, or things to try, let me know.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need this simple, sample project to build and run on my machine. It won't. It will if I setup a fresh Ubuntu install inside of a VM, for example. I do not know what the difference is between the VM and my machine. They are configured the same.

Comment: Just create a new user and try building from there

Comment: That worked, but is overkill ... just short of rebuilding the entire machine from scratch. It seems weird to recreate a user account just to fix the problem.